# Gradle Error: Project with path ''could not be found in root project ''

Tags: scala, gradle, build, akka, akka-http

Check out the link for the project structure image.

```
RootModule
  --- ChildModule1
  --- ChildModule2
  --- ChildModule3
```

ChildModule3 depends on ChildModule2 depends on ChildModule1

Each settings.gradle defines

```
include ':PreviousModule'

project(':PreviousModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../PreviousModule')
```

And build.gradle contains

```
implementation project(':PreviousModule')
```

I even tried

```
compile project(':PreviousModule')
```

but no help.

[Project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehZFg.png)

Comment: If this is supposed to be a single multi-module project, then you should have only one settings.gradle file, in the root module. If these are 3 independant projects, then they shouldn't include each other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to continue setting it up as a multi-module project, you would want only one settings.gradle and that would be inside the root project. Please remove others as they are unnecessary

RootModule -> settings.gradle

```groovy
include "ChildModule1"
include "ChildeModule2"
//...
```

then in ChildModule2 -> build.gradle

```groovy
dependencies {
  compile project('ChildModule1')
}
```

Comment: Every answer I found on the internet missed one point from msuper:
>
you would want only one settings.gradle and that would be inside the root project
You save my day!

Comment: It`s not work for me
```A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hub.sample_service'.
> Project with path 'hub.common_service' could not be found in root project 'hub.sample_service'.

```

Comment: @WBLord, same for me. I still struggling, u manage to resolve this?

Comment: Until now, i still not sure whether to put colon or not, inside the include argument.   i.e  include ":ChildModule1" or include "ChildModule1"